# How to send HTTP PUT request using ionic2 native http plugin?

Tags: rest, cordova, http, ionic2, put

I am trying to send an HTTP `put` request from an ionic 2 app using an [http native plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/), however, from the doc, I see only `post` and `get` request methods are implemented.

**First:** I would like to know if http methods `delete` and `put`are not really implemented (as I might not be looking at right place in the docs).

**Second:** If those are not implemented, how we can generate `put` and `delete` from an ionic 2 app? Is it possible to do it at low level, yet without the need to do modification to the plugin native/library code?

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:** There is a pull request for `put`, `delete` and `postJSON` implementation (https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP/pull/105), however from September 2016 till now April 2017 it is not merged with master.

**Update 2:** First I would like to thank @Jamil Hijjawi for the answer. That solved the problem. But in the way, I would like to mention the solution 2 requires some server configuration to get around CORS, so I chose the first one. Also there is a nice article https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-in-ionic-2-with-ionic-native/ that explains how to use a cordova plugin that is not in "Ionic Native", I do recommend to go through it. I would like to point out a section, as:

> The way in which you use a non Ionic Native plugin in Ionic 2 is the same as the way you would use it in any Cordova project, which is however the plugin’s documentation says you should use it. However, there are some extra steps you need to take because TypeScript will cause some problems.

Going further it explains that we need to declare the globally exported variable `cordovaHTTP` by the plugin in somewhere like `declarations.d.ts` so typescript knows about that. Once declared, no dependency injection is needed. Following is a code snippet I have used in a random Component function.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private _platform: Platform
  ) {
    this._platform.ready().then(() => {

      // ========== We need this part
      cordovaHTTP.put('http://192.168.0.5:8081/test-route', {
        really: "Yea!"
      }, {}, (res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      }, (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      // ========== till here, as for the example of usage
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

The `cordova-http` plugin only support `GET` and `POST`, so if you want to use `PUT` install the plugin directly from the author who made the pull request repo https://github.com/spuentesp/cordova-HTTP using this command `ionic plugin add https://github.com/spuentesp/cordova-HTTP`

but there is no implemented declaration for these APIs from `ionic-native`, so you can declare `cordovaHTTP` namespace in `declarations.d.ts` and use the API you want

**Option 2:**

Use the `Http` service in angular

```
this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
```

Http class doc https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am having problems with the declaration part. How to declare cordovaHTTP namespace in declarations.d.ts? Can you add some code snippet please?

Comment: You are welcome, add `declare var cordovaHTTP: any;` to `declarations.d.ts`

Comment: I am doing the same, but I get HTTP is not defined. I guess I need to link some JS file to the definition file, however, I cannot figure out how

Comment: are you able to do a POST with data?